# Appium Desktop recorder is using Xpath instead of Id

Tags: appium, appium-android, nosuchelementexception, appium-desktop

I'm exploring my Native App with Appium DeskTop. For an inputfield Appium Desktop is showing in the 'Find By Selector Window' an Id and a XPath expression.

When I recorded a Sendkeys action to this inputfield Appium DeskTop shows in the Recorder Window that the XPath expression is used to locate the Element instead of the Id. This is not what I expected, I expected the Id being used to locate the element.

I tried to use the Id in my Testprogram to locate the element, this is giving, when Explicit waiting for Visbilty of the Element, see C# code below:

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("companyname")));
IWebElement bedrijf = (IWebElement)driver.FindElementById("companyname");
bedrijf.Click();
bedrijf.SendKeys("IBM");
```

Then the following exception appears:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException
```

What kind of an Id is presenting Appium Desktop here?

[image]

Comment: Can you add screen shot with the UI Automator View for the element that you are trying to locate?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. With the left panel showing the UI of the App?

Comment: Yes, With UI and highlight the element on which you want perform action. Also Please add your code here.

Comment: I replaced the printscreen with the one you asked for.

Comment: I added the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use resource-id. For native android apps, usually id attribute is used as **resource-id**.

```
IWebElement bedrijf = (IWebElement)driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@resource-id='companyname']"))
```

Comment: My question was about the behaviour of Appium Desktop Selected Element and And Appium Desktop recorder pane.